# Sharebar floating Restriction - WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a Sharebar plugin in my wordpress blog, which is floating vertically on the left side of the post page. I like to know is there a way to restrict the floating property of the bar to a particular section. All i want is the bar to end before the footer starts.

Comment: @Rafee: Could you explain how this is jQuery related?

Comment: @polarblau added some jquery function where scroller function is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function cevhershare_scroll() {
    var p = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var w = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery(cevhershare).css('position',((p+10)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'absolute');
    jQuery(cevhershare).css('top',((p+10)>start) ? '10px' : '');
}
```

The above code functions on scrolling and i have added some below code that i havn't it, you can use with

```
jQuery(cevhershare).css('bottom',((p+10)>start) ? 'giveyournumberfromfooterpx' : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

what are u going to do with your fixed property if the window shrinks? say if the the window is a third of the size. this will certainly not look professional.